# How do you add a custom context menu to run an SPE script not in the scripts section?

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-editor

I would like to have a custom context menu like the following:

[image: Hello Menu]

Since this menu item does not follow the typical integration points for SPE, how would I go about making it work with a script?

Comment: Thanks Michael, This is very useful, wonder if we can pass dynamic values to the script from the context Menu?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first step would be to create a custom script in one of your modules.

For example, create a custom SPE module using the wizard followed by whatever library structure you prefer. Check out the [official SPE docs](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules) for additional details.

[image: Module]

```
Show-Alert -Title "Hello!"
Close-Window # Causes the runner dialog to close automatically
```

Copy the item ID of the script.

Switch to the core database and create a new menu item. For the demo we'll create it at the following path:

```
# Item path
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default/Say Hello
```

[image: Menu item]

The **Message** field should contain the following where the script parameter matches the item ID of the script.

```
item:executescript(id=$Target,script={5BCE1B7C-E484-4809-B34F-C1F2B65905DD}, scriptDb=master)
```

Switch back to the **master** database and give the new menu item a try.

[image: Message]

**Note:** Big thanks to [Kurt Bilde](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/612/kurt-bilde) for asking about it on Sitecore Chat.

Comment: This works - thanks for sharing this one!!!